# showModalDialog deprecated and is out...suffering TMI of what to replace it with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using showModalDialog quite blissfully until the other day when IE 10 started acting up with it. A little Googling revealed that showModalDialog is deprecated.

So my search began for a replacement and that is when I started getting overwhelmed at all the different options.

Since I am working a large existing app I can't just go plugging in whatever library and call it a happy day. Further I need to block execution (or exec a call back function) when the user is done interacting with my popup.

Since we are using jquery 1.4 I thought to use it but the examples I saw popped a div content and that is not my scenario.

Going back to Google I was again overwhelmed with all the modal libraries etc. out there so I was hoping someone could cut through the noise for me.

Here is a typical code snippet:

```
function LaunchDialog(dialogID, typeName, SubGridName)
{
   var left = Number((screen.width / 2) - (700 / 2));
   var top = Number((screen.height / 2) - (500 / 2));

   var recordId = window.parent......getId();

   var serverUri = window......create('/.../rundialog.aspx');

   window.showModalDialog(serverUri + '?DialogId=%7b' ..... 'top='+top+', left='+left);

  //reload refresh grid only--this is the line for callback
  window.parent.RefreshGrids(SubGridName);
}
```

Switching to window.open I lose my modal dialog effect....which is to say the user could change focus and not complete the dialog questions. Further the code no longer blocks.

So am I just naive to think that it should be as easy as changing window.showmodaldialog to newcrossbrowsermodaldialog(parm1, parm2) etc?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Yes...it was popping existing div content as seen in the example...I went through api but didn't see where I could hand it a url...?

Comment: Incidentally, `showModalDialog` is being removed from both [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=981796) (Firefox) and [Blink](http://crbug.com/345831) (Chrome/Opera) because of security problems it introduces.

Comment: @Powerlord what I thought was interesting was that IE was the first to give me fits...I figured they would be last to let it go.